# Better way to store big similar objects

Tags: c++, class, vector

So I have a 'big' class `A`, and another class `B` one which will hold a vector of at least 100 objects of `A`. It does not seem to be a good idea to store all objects in class `B` as a `vector<A>` since a lot of info can be reused.

I was thinking about having a template in class `B` which holds all similar properties of `A` and then create a `vector<A*>` to it. But that makes them all the same...

So is there a way of storing similar variables of a class so that only the few differences need to be stored multiple times?

### Minimal working example

```
#include <iostream>

// suppose an int is big:
struct A { // create struct which holds 3 ints
    A() : a(0),b(0),c(0) {} //ctor

    void print() { // print all variables
        cout << a << ", " << b << ", " << c << endl;
    }
    int a,b,c;
};

class B { // create object that holds a vector of A
public:
    B(int vectorSize) {
        vector_A.resize(vectorSize);
        vector_ptr_A.resize(vectorSize);
    }

    void initValues() {
        ///////////////////////////////////////
        // METHOD 1
        vector_A.resize(vectorSize); // resize 
        for (int i=0; i<vector_A.size(); ++i) {
            vector_A[i].a = rand() % 100; // randomize A::a
            vector_A[i].b = 5;            // only B wants A::b to be 5
            vector_A[i].c = 10;           // only B wants A::c to be 10
        }
        ///////////////////////////////////////

        ///////////////////////////////////////
        // METHOD 2
        A_template.b = 5;  // only B wants A::b to be 5
        A_template.c = 10; // only B wants A::c to be 10
        vector_ptr_A.resize(vectorSize,&A_template); // point to template
        for (int i=0; i<vector_ptr_A.size(); ++i) {
            vector_A[i].a = rand() % 100; // randomize A::a
        }
        ///////////////////////////////////////
    }

    void print1() { // prints vector_A[i]
        for (int i = 0; i < vector_A.size(); ++i) {
            vector_A[i].print();
        }
    }
        void print2() { // prints vector_ptr_A[i]
        for (int i=0; i < vector_ptr_A.size(); ++i) {
            vector_ptr_A[i]->print();
        }
    }

    // method 1
    vector<A> vector_A; // a big, big vector

    // method 2
    A A_template;
    vector<A*> vector_ptr_A; // all the same
};

int main() {
    srand( time(NULL) );
    B b(10);
    b.initValues();

    cout << "METHOD 1\n";
    b.print1();             // as desired, but inefficient
    cout << "\nMETHOD 2\n";
    b.print2();             // all the same output
}
```

---

### Edit

Some clarification because the minimal working example is a bit confusing. I have also adapted it now to make it more clear.

The members of class `A` are meant to be set by `B` and the user. The user will for example define `A::a` for each element of the vector (which is represented by the random) and the other 2 (`A::b` and `A::c`) are defined by `B`. Class `A` is not a class only used by `B`, but also by the user or any other class.

**So basically I'm asking for a method so I don't have to set `A::b` and `A::c` for every element of the vector, but only once. `A::a` is different for every element which I should set.**

To situate why I want this: class `A` is in my program a `Sprite` class and `B` must be able to print sprites as tiles and is named `TileMap`. The vector in `TileMap` thus holds a lot of `Sprite`s all able to be drawn on the window, but a lot of info is exactly the same for all those tiles (texture tile size, drawing tile size, texture file, etc) and I don't want to set all these variables for every tile. I'd like to create some sort of template which can be used for every `Sprite` in the vector. This way is not only easier and less space consuming, but also more safe: I know all these values will be exactly the same.

Comment: Having a vector of objects is actually using _less_ space than having a vector of pointers to the objects. Reason being that with the vector of pointers you have the space of the pointers in addition to the space of the objects. The major difference between the two vectors is where the objects are stored, that's all.

Comment: If you want a vector of _different_ objects, look into [Boost Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/any.html) or [Boost Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/variant.html) libraries.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: If `b` and `c` are supposed to be the same for every `A`, why aren't they `static` data members of `A`? And if they have to be the same for all `A`s contained by the same `B`, then why aren't the values assigned to `b` and `c` depending on `B` in any way?

Comment: and notice though that this modulo operation does not generate uniformly distributed random numbers in the span (unless RAND_MAX is multiple of 100 on your machine). You should use this RAND_MAX, but... it is not so important - you will have just slightly skewed distribution

Comment: @AndyProwl `b` and `c` should be set by class `B` and may be given an other value by someone else. It is done this way just for simplicity.

Comment: @cf16 I know, but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some clarification needed, but I will go with my understanding of your question.

```
struct Common_A_Members
{
  int x;
  double y;
};

struct Uncommon_A_Members
{
  unsigned int this_member_changes;
};

struct A : public Common_A_Members, public Uncommon_A_Members
{
  A(const Common_A_Members& c, const Uncommon_A_Members& d)
  : Common_A_Members(c), Uncommon_A_Members(d)
  { ; }
};


struct B
{
  Common_A_Members a_common;
  std::vector<Uncommon_A_Members> a_uncommon;
};
```

In the above example, the concept class is split into two pieces, one piece contains values that don't change (Common_A_Members) and values that do change (Uncommon_A_Members).  This allows for `B` to have one member of *constant* data and a vector of `changing` data.  The `A` concept class has a constructor that combines the constant data and the changing data.

The two members in `B` are a set.  The set would need to be copied or repeated for those concept classes that have different constant values.

The theory is to factor out constant data from changing data.

Comment: I like your thinking, however I don't wish to change `A` only for `B`. I can maybe create a vector of a struct in `B` which holds all the uncommon values and only one object of `A`.

Answer (score 1):

If variables b,c are always identical for all instances of A - make them static in A.

If variables b,c are identical for the set of instances of A stored in one instance of B, consider placing b,c in B instead.

If variables b,c are identical for only some set of A, consider factor out b,c to it's own "config" class C, and store smart pointer to C in A. This assumes b,c to be large enough, or shared by enough instances, for the extra management to be worthwhile.

Btw, are you sure your print2() function should use vector_ptr_A[0] and not vector_ptr_A[i]?
(I would've asked this in a comment if I could...)

Edit: Reference version of third option:

```
class A_Config // stores common parts of A
{
public:
  A_Config(int a, int b) : m_a(a), m_b(b) {}
private:
  int m_a;
  int m_b;
};

class A // store parts changing for each instance and a reference to the common parts
{
public:
  A(int changing, A_Config& shared) : m_changing(changing), m_shared(shared) {}
private:
  int m_changing;
  A_Config& m_shared;
};

class B
{
public:
  B(int a, int b) : conf(a,b) {} // the common parts of A initialized 
                                 // only once when B is created

  void add_A(int changing) // add the changing parts when A is added
  {
    v.push_back( A(changing, conf) );
  }

private:
  A_Config conf;
  vector<A> v;
};
```

Comment: Can you explain the third method? Like creating a structure in `A` which holds theses variables? And yes that was a typo, thanks.

Comment: @didii I edited the answer to reflect my thinking. Added example code.

Answer (score 0):

Just another way:

```
std::vector <std::reference_wrapper<A>> vector_ref_A;
```

Example:

```
A a, b, c;

std::vector < std::reference_wrapper < A >> vector_ref_A = {a, b, c};

for (int i = 0; i < vector_ref_A.size(); ++i) {
    vector_ref_A[i].get().randomize();
}

for (int i = 0; i < vector_ref_A.size(); ++i) {
    vector_ref_A[i].get().print();
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what this is :p